# Google hijacking online services Chrome/Chromium

Tags: google-chrome

Firefox is my primary web browser, but I had to adopt a copy of Chrome/Chromium in order to run business apps (only run that particular app) that Firefox could not run. Since then, every time Firefox is opened (with Chromium not running) a giant black tag appears on the lower right of the task bar, wanting me to switch to Chrome as primary browser.

Is Chrome/Chromium data-mining me?

Unless it installed malware into my system, why is it showing up on Firefox now? I do not think repositories should contain malware labeled as "A Free Web browser". Chrome and Firefox are never opened at the same time since I installed them.

Comment: Can you provide a screenshot of what you see?